# How to append html in cypher code

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
$query="START n=node:node_auto_index(name:"Ashish") CREATE UNIQUE n-[n_f]->(r{con:"<img src="anypic.jpg""})";
```

how  do  i  add a  html;  code in  a  neo4j  node.Is it  Possible?

Comment: I   doudt  there is  a  problem with  conceation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nested double quotes. You need to escape them as per your language. PHP?

In Cypher, you can escape quotes with `\"`.

http://console.neo4j.org/r/db6url

Answer (score 2):

With Cypher, you could do just

```
CREATE (Test {content:'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body><h1>Test Page</h1><img src="anypic.jpg"></body></html>'})
```

Live console link: http://console.neo4j.org/r/nki3cf